# Can I expect DOM to be ready in the next VM tick

Tags: javascript, dom, browser

Once HTML is loaded, a browser parses it in a **synchronous** manner. Usually we wait for the DOM be ready using `DOMContentLoaded` event. But I'm wondering if the DOM will **always** be ready in the next VM tick? Can I rely on the DOM being availabe if I run a callback in the next VM tick using any of the  async functions like `setTimeout` or `Promise.resolve().then()`?

A link to a spec extract that guarantees that is appreciated.

An example would be a framework or a library that is always bootstrapped asynchronously and doesn't add a listener for `DOMContentLoaded` event.

Comment: I have tried using timeout with 0 and DOMContentLoaded event listener, always DOMContentLoaded  is called first(in chrome). I feel timeout script is also parsed first after that it is executed and DOMContentLoaded  is fired once the parsing is finished

Answer (score 0):

VM ticks are irrelevant. The callbacks are called by an [event loop](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loops) which processes *tasks*. The DOM will be in a stable state when the task begins. All `setTimeout` does when the timeout is reached is to [queue a task](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#queue-a-task) to be processed by the event loop.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I know all that. What is your statement _The DOM will be in a stable state when the task begins_ based on?